# How to print two variables line by line

Tags: bash, shell

I am looking for a way to print line by line on shell.

For example, I have the following variables A and B that contains:

```
| A | B | 
| a | d | 
| b | c | 
| c | b | 
| d | a |
```

What I want as the output is:

```
a d
b c
c b
d a
```

I have tried

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=" "}{
  getline line < "$A"
  print $0,line
} ' "$B"
```

But this doesn't work.
A and B are multi-lined strings. For example A is a*\n*b*\n*c*\n*d*\n*
Please no 'columns' or 'paste' method.

Comment: What are `$a` and `$b` supposed to be in that awk snippet? `$a` in the script will not be expanded as a shell variable because of the single quotes so it will be a literal `$a`.

Comment: @anubhava `$2,$4` unless you use `-F \|`.

Comment: Actual code showing how `A` and `B` are set would be more useful than your description.

Comment: What is `$a` and what is `$b`? Are they variables containing multi-line strings, or filenames? Please [edit] your question to make it more clear.

Comment: `awk -F '[ |]+' 'NR >1 {print $2, $3}'`?

Comment: And what's wrong with a `paste` invocation? For example `paste <(echo "$A") <(echo "$B")`...

Answer (score 1):

Try with this command:

```bash
while read -u7 a && read -u8 b; do echo "[$a] [$b]"; done 7<<<"$A" 8<<<"$B"
```

or

```bash
while read -u7 a && read -u8 b; do echo "[$a] [$b]"; done \
    7< <(echo "$A") 8< <(echo "$B")
```

Here `read -u7 a` means read from file descriptor 7 into `a` variable,
`7<<<"$A"` means redirect the contents of `$A` to file descriptor 7,
and `7< <(echo "$A")` means redirect the echo output to file descriptor 7.

For example, if I have `A=$(seq 10 15); B=$(seq 20 25);` , the result is:

```
[10] [20]
[11] [21]
[12] [22]
[13] [23]
[14] [24]
[15] [25]
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the reason you don't want to use `paste` is that you want to further process the value pairs.

If it's sufficient to do this processing in *shell* code, consider [tivn's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30221687/45375) or [Charles Duffy's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30222186/45375).

If you do want to use `awk` for further processing, as in your solution attempt, consider *combining* `paste` with `awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Sample input
A=$'a\nb\nc\nd'
B=$'d\nc\nb\na'

paste <(echo "$A") <(echo "$B") | awk '{ print "Pair #" NR ": ", $1, $2 }'
```

- `paste <(echo "$A") <(echo "$B")` merges corresponding lines from the two input variables, with the origin lines separated by a `\t` instance.
- `awk`'s default field splitting then provides the respective values as fields `$1` and `$2` for each input line.

---

As for **why your `awk` command didn't work**:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=" "}{
  getline line < "$A"
  print $0,line
} ' "$B"
```

- Your `awk` script is *single-quoted*, yet it looks like you're attempting to reference *shell* variable `$A` inside.

  - Since the shell doesn't interpret single-quoted strings, it is `awk` that will interpret `$A`, which is not the intent;
    generally, though it is *good* practice to use single-quoted strings, as to avoid confusion between what the shell expands ahead of time and what `awk` sees; use `-v varName=varValue` options to pass shell variable values to `awk`.
  - `awk` then interprets `$A` the _field (`$`) with the index stored in *awk* variable `A` - since variable `A` is not defined, this is either equivalent to `$0`, the current input line (GNU awk, mawk), or a runtime error (BSD awk).
  - Even if you did manage to use *shell* variable `"$A"`, the `getline line <` approach wouldn't work, because it requires a *filename*; thus, you'd have to write the contents of `$A` to a (temporary) file first, and *specify that file's path* in lieu of `$A` in the `awk` script.
  - As you can see, this gets cumbersome, and, generally, `getline` is rarely the right approach - see http://awk.info/?tip/getline
- Also, you're passing `"$B"`, even though it contains *data*, as if it were a *filename* to `awk`.

  - To truly pass the data, you must use *stdin*; in `bash`, the simplest approach here is to use `<<<"$B"` (a so-called [here-string](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument?action=show&redirect=HereString)).

Answer (score 1):

Loading each string's elements into an array makes pairwise processing easier. For instance:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^- must be bash, not sh, for arrays to be a supported feature

IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a array_a <<<"$A"
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a array_b <<<"$B"

for idx in "${!array_a[@]}"; do
  printf '%s\t|%s\n' "${array_a[$idx]}" "${array_b[$idx]}"
done
```